# How to format multivalve picklist values for query

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, visualforce-component

I have an Opportunity object that has a multivalve picklist field called Support_Required__c. I want to use Support_Required__c to query for any Account whose Support__c (multivalve picklist) - any of the values matches Support_Required__c. opp. Support_Required__c returns `'value1;value2;value3'`, but I want to change it to `'value1','value2','value3'` so that it will return any Account that matches either one of the values.

Code:

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static List<Account> getAccounts(Id oppId) {
        Volunteer_Opportunity__c opp = [Select Name, Support_Required__c FROM Volunteer_Opportunity__c WHERE id = :oppId];

    System.debug('opp.support ' + opp.Support_Required__c); // 'value1;value2;value3'   

    List<Account> account = [Select Name, Support__c, Locations__c FROM Account where Support__c includes (:opp.Support_Required__c)];
    return account;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My Solution - I query each Support one by one, then put them into an array.

```
        String[] supports = opp.Support_Required__c.split(';');     

        List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();

        for(String s : supports){
            List<Account> acc = [Select Name, Support__c, Locations__c FROM Account where Support__c includes (:s)];
            for(Account elem : acc){
                if(!accounts.contains(elem)){
                    accounts.add(elem);
                }
            }
        }

        return accounts;
```